# Using When vs Verify for validating method calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

This confuses me, let me explain with basic example;

```java
public void search(String name) {
        // some more
        Response response = component.findByName(name);
        // some more action with response
    }
```

So when I write tests for it;

```java
@Test
public void search_givenName_shouldOk() {
    Example example = new Example();
    Component component= Mockito.mock(Component.class);
    String name = "test";
    when(component.findByName(eq(name))).thenReturn(mock(Response.class));

    example.search(name);
    verify(component, times(1)).findByName(eq(name));
}
```

So actually when we write when(...) clause with eq(name) input, did not it already validate our test case? Otherwise findByName would not return Response and further calls would not be okay. So when we again verified it with verify(..), is not it double work?

Comment: Again same stackoverflow community without understanding question, directly refers to documentation or duplicate question. -> "I know these. I think people are ready to refer documentation without understand.I say; when you use 'eq' in when input, you already validated if it is called with that input. Than in the verify section you say 'verify if my function is called with exactly this input', but you already forced your when query with 'eq' which verifies it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` does not verify anything, it just **instruct** the mocked object how to behave **when** it will be called.

So your assertion

> when you use 'eq' in when input, you already validated if it is called
>   with that input.

is false.

So the line:

```
when(component.findByName(eq(name))).thenReturn(mock(Response.class));
```

means "Mocked component, can you return that nice response when (and if if) your method `findByName` is invoked with this particular name."

When you have mocked all the desired behaviors, and called the actual tested method, you still need to `verify` that the mocked objects behaved like you expected them to behave.

Answer (score 2):

You use `when()` if you want to mock the behaviour of a function and therefore avoid testing it.

Use `verify()` to check that a function has been called as a part of tested function.

These are 2 different concepts. In your case the `when()` does not make sence as you want to test the function. Furthermore if a tested funciton is part of a `Example` class, you don't want that mocked either. You only mock what you don't want to test.